# return a Json from function after a while?

Tags: php

In iOS i know i use blocks to get a value from function that do some background task.

I have a function that goes to server and get data .  Then i want to return that data to the caller , so i do this without success :

```
  function readFromServer($deviceid) 
{


    //PARSE API KEYS
    $appId = 'xxx';  
    $restKey = 'yay';  

    $deviceToFind='"' . $deviceid . '"' ;

    $params = 'where={"Devices":{"$in":[' . $deviceToFind . ']}}';

    $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/USERS?' . urlencode($params);  


     $headers = array(  
   "Content-Type: application/json",  
   "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,  
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey  
 );  





 $rest = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_GET,1);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
 $response = curl_exec($rest);  
 $json = json_decode($response, true);


 //   print_r($json['results'][0]['UserID']);  //works !



 curl_close($rest); 
  return  $json
    }
```

Call it with :

```
$foundUser= readFromServer($deviceID); 

print_r($foundUser['results'][0]['UserID']);
```

Prints nothing (**when i do knows that function gets back the data from server**)

**EDIT**:
Inside the function i get value with :

```
 print_r($json['results'][0]['UserID']);
```

Comment: `var_dump($foundUser);`?

Comment: @Federico what ? :) not sure i got you..

Comment: `$url` seems pretty undefined to me. You should test for [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) as well

Comment: @Jan you you got me, i asked another question, but whats the connection between them? yes it did printed that value , now , i want to return it.

Comment: let's us see your real `readFromServer` function please.

Comment: @Curnelious No problem with asking different questions but the problem must be somewhere else if you just return the json object from the function.

Comment: @Federico you got it, check my question again, i have the full function.

Comment: If this is really the code in question (copied) there is a parsing error (it lacks a semicolon after `return $json`).

Comment: My bet is that you see a blank page, and you think that `print_r($foundUser['results'][0]['UserID']);` prints nothing. But you got a fatal error. Enable `dispaly_errors`

Comment: Can you also post the output from a file with your top two code snippets and the `print` inside the function uncommented? @Frederico My bet aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is really the copied code, you're lacking a semicolon after the return statement:

```
curl_close($rest);
return  $json;
//         (here)
```

As mentionned in the comments, enable the errors with:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: @Curnelious Twice in a row :-) Nevermind, glad it worked out!

Comment: but next time do some debug on your own :P

Comment: I do a lots of debugging, i actually had left a great job to debug this project but thats another issue :)